# Поиск и переход. Split View and Search bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, search

Имеется Split Viw для универсального приложения. В "Мастере" вида таблица, с данными поисковой строкой (Search Bar). Когда поиск неактивен переход на вид "Детали" происходит.

При отфильтрованной таблице с помощью Search Bar и при нажатии по ячекйе перехода на вид "Детали" не осуществляется.

Как осуществить переход на "Детали" при включенном поиске?

Ссалка на проект: [Тыц](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nhso0ukzxkp0hvo/AAAETilKGxyTaHf_TyBryPXMa?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //
//  MasterViewController.m
//  TestSpl
//
//  Created by Олег Дворядкин on 30.12.15.
//  Copyright © 2015 ###. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController {
    NSArray *recipes;
    NSArray *searchResults;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    [recipes init];
    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [recipes count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{
    NSIndexPath *idx = indexPath;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) { // если поиск активен делаем переход на "Детали", в протвном случае будет двойной переход если поиск неактивен
        NSLog([searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showDetail" sender: self]; // переход на "детали"
    }
    else {
    NSLog([recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog([searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
            [controller setDetailItem:[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // отображаем выбранную ячейку в label в DetalView

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog([recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
            [controller setDetailItem:[recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  // отображаем выбранную ячейку в label в DetalView

        }
    }

}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",   /// поиск по любому совпадению
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];     // настройка вона ячеек
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:0.3];                           // закрашиваем через одну ячейки серым фоном
        UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = color;
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

    }


    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;         //несколько строк в тексте лабеле для отображения длинной информации в ячеках таблицы

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8.0];//Helvetica
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; // button '>'
}

/*
 - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
 {
 [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]
 scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
 objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

 return YES;
 }

 */
@end
```

Сделал, [ссылка на проект](https://yadi.sk/d/wXAq1V3cmkoYi)

Comment: можно в ответе оставить только код относящийся к решению проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

У вас оригинальная таблица и отфильтрованная таблица это не один и тот же объект, по этому первая таблица делает переходы - она так настроена в storyboard, а вторая нет. Для перехода их второй таблицы (при включенном поиске), вам надо добавить метод `-(void)tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` и в нем написать `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];` плюс дописать метод `-prepareForSegue:sender:` чтобы он читал данные из обоих dataSource в зависимости от ситуации

Comment: Max, при такой реализации ([self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self]), возникают проблемы с двойным показом "Деталей" при пустом поиске. Конечно, это лечится сравнением на длину поисковой строки. НО это костыли ))). Также, при активном поиске меняется внешний вид таблицы с отфильтрованными данными. Думаю есть правильный способ, но я не могу его найти )))

Comment: правильный способ отказаться от перехода в сториборде и делать оба варианта перехода программно.